# Magento 1.9 Contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I want to create a contact form where customers can contact me on different email to the one specified in the Magento back-end configuration.

I have a form.phtml file in `/http/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/contacts/form.phtml` and I want to have exactly the same form but on different cms page which will send the information to a different email address.

Do I copy the `form.phtml` and name `form2.phtml` but how do I adjust it so it sends the email to a different email address?

My goal is to create a "contact us" where customer can fill in some information and then "submit" it and it will send the information to a specified email.

Here is my `form.phtml`:

```
            <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
            </div>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wide">
                            <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Company Name') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                    <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
            //]]>
            </script>
```

I have created a new CMS page in magento back end and included this:

`{{block type="core/template" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}`

It displayes the form correctly but where does it send the email to? How do I adjust it or change it without changing different forms? Bare in mind that I do have a standard "contact us" page with email specified and I do not want to change it but instead send this form to another email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another custom form, like [this Inchoo tuto](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/), then you can include the form in your cms page according this tuto like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="form.custom" form_action="/simpleContact/index/sendemail" template="inchoo/simple_contact.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give it a go and let you know how it went. Once more thank you for directing me.

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Comment: Hey, Since you recomended this way, you might help me with this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181154/magento-1-9-custom-module-form?noredirect=1#comment248786_181154

Comment: It's probably quick and easy to fix but drives me insane for hours now!

Comment: Look my answer in that post

Comment: @PRINCE  how can i add feedback form in all pages, my feedback contains, php,html,css,js

Answer (score 1):

{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}