# 2 contact us forms with different email configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, contact-form

I want to copy magento "contact us" form, however, set a different configuration to it.

Now, "contact us" form sends information to support@company.com.
I want "contact us 2" to be exactly the same as "contact us" but send information to sales@company.com.

I want 2 different contact forms on the site, and each sends information to different email address.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want new backend field for configuring the email or use one of the store email field ?

Comment: I have created a new simple module now to handle it. Still working on it but nearly finishing now. I will post the answer once I have finished. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this tutorial to create a new simple module for form:

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/

Really easy to follow with good explanations.

Please find this magento.stackexachnge threat useful too if you want to send more information via `$mail->setBodyText`

[Magento 1.9 Contact form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181080/magento-1-9-contact-form/181102#181102)