# Magento 1.9 Custom Module Form $mail = new Zend_Mail(); include more $params

Tags: magento-1.9, email, zend-framework, contact-form

I created a simple custom module and have a problem with `$parmas` which I can't figure out for hours now.

Here is the IndexController.php responsible for it:

```
        public function sendemailAction()
        {
            //Fetch submited params
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
     
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setBodyText($params['name']);
            $mail->setFrom($params['email'], $params['name']);
            $mail->addTo('greg@domain.co.uk', 'Some Recipient');
            $mail->setSubject('Test Wholesale_SimpleContact Module');
            try {
                $mail->send();
            }        
            catch(Exception $ex) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Wholesale_SimpleContact.');
     
            }
     
            //Redirect back to index action of (this) wholesale-simplecontact controller
            $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/');
        }
```

In the `$mail->setBodyText($params['name']);` I need more `$params` to be included. These are: `name` `email` `business_name` `business_address` `telephone_number`.

I tried many different things such as:

```
        $mail->setBodyText($params['name'], $params['email'], $params['business_name'], $params['business_address'], $params['telephone_number']);
```

But no luck. They all work individually so they are set correctly. I just can't get them to be sent together.

UPDATED CONTROLLER:

```
        public function sendemailAction() {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
            $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
            $businessName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_name');
            $businessAddress = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_address');
            $telephoneNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('telephone_number');
            $allParams = $name;
            $allParams .= $email;
            $allParams .= $businessName;
            $allParams .= $businessAddress;
            $allParams .= $telephoneNumber;
            $body = $name.' '.$email.' '.$businessName.' '.$businessAddress.' '.$telephoneNumber
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setBodyText($body)
            $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
            $mail->addTo('greg@domain.co.uk', 'Some Recipient');
            $mail->setSubject('Test Wholesale_SimpleContact Module');
            try {
                $mail->send();
            }     
            catch(Exception $ex) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Wholesale_SimpleContact.');
            }
            //Redirect back to index action of (this) wholesale-simplecontact controller
            $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/');
        }
```

phtml file:

```
            <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Wholesale Contact') ?></h1>
            </div>

            <form id="contactForm" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wholesale-simplecontact/') ?>index/sendemail" method="post">

                          <div class="fieldset">
                            <fieldset class="group-select">
                                <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                                <ul>
                                <li class="fields">
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <label for="name">Name <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                         
                                            <input name="name" id="name" title="Name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                         
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="email">Email <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="required-entry input-text validate-email" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="business_name">Business Name <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="business_name" id="business_name" title="Business Name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="business_address">Business Address <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="business_address" id="business_address" title="Business Address" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="telephone_number">Telephone Number <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="telephone_number" id="telephone_number" title="Telephone Number" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                         
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                         
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="comment">Comment</label><br />
                         
                                            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="Comment" class="required-entry input-text" style="height:100px;" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </li>
                                        
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>
                
                
                <div class="button-set">
                    <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
                    <button style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="button" type="submit"><span>Submit <br></span></button>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: please confirm whether u r unable to send the mail?

Comment: No no, everything works fine, it's just in the body of the email, I want to include the $params mentioned above but can't figure out how :/ Only 1 is visible in the emauil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!-- I haven't tested it but tell me about a result-->
public function sendemailAction() {
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $businessName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_name');
    $businessAddress = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_address');
    $telephoneNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('telephone_number');
    $body = $name.' '.$email.' '.$businessName.' '.$businessAddress.' '.$telephoneNumber;
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setBodyText($body);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addTo('greg@domain.co.uk', 'Some Recipient');
    $mail->setSubject('Test Wholesale_SimpleContact Module');
    try {
        $mail->send();
    }     
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Wholesale_SimpleContact.');
    }
    //Redirect back to index action of (this) wholesale-simplecontact controller
    $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/');
}
```

Comment: Hi, that didn't work. I didn't send any information this time. Only blank email. setFrom didn't send any information  too.

Comment: Try to remove the `s` from getParams from $name, $email, $businessName, $businessAddress, $telephoneNumber like this `$name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');` sorry i haven't test it look also if you have some errors, and you should have all fields in your form with the same name field !

Comment: After removing the `s` like you mentioned. The  `$mail->setFrom($email, $name);` is now back working, however, there is nothing being sent in the `$mail->setBodyText`

Comment: ok, try this: `$mail->setBodyText($name, $email, $businessName, $businessAddress, $telephoneNumber);`

Comment: Only $name variable came though to my email.

Comment: How many field have you in your form ?, if you just have a name field, you will get only this one

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: You have well the `<form> </form>` tag around the fields ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, see the post now.

Comment: Try this: `$mail->setBodyText($businessAddress);` and look if you get the value ?

Comment: Yes it did work. The `$businessAddress` came through fine.

Comment: That mean that you get well the paramaters, try this: `$allParams = $name; $allParams .=$email; $allParams .=$businessName; $allParams .=$businessAddress; $allParams .=$telephoneNumber;`  then `$mail->setBodyText($allParams);` Afterthat you format the content like you want

Comment: I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setBodyText() on a non-object in /domains/dev.vampirevape.co.uk/http/app/code/local/Wholesale/SimpleContact/controllers/IndexController.php on line 38`

Comment: add this `$body =$name.' '.$email.' '.$businessName.' '.$businessAddress.' '.$telephoneNumber`  before`$mail = new Zend_Mail();` then put $mail->setBodyText($body)

Comment: See my updated controller in my post (that what it looks like now). I get this error now `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE) in /domains/dev.vampirevape.co.uk/http/app/code/local/Wholesale/SimpleContact/controllers/IndexController.php on line 39` and like 39 is: `$mail = new Zend_Mail();`

Comment: Ahh I had a `;` missing :D all sorted and working !!!!

Comment: Ouuuuf finally, it works :)

Comment: I'll update a answer now, just in case someone else is having troubles! Or update yours and I'll accept it :)

Comment: It's done now...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, +1 also for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can add like html

$html = 'Your Name'.$params['name'];

$html .= 'Your Email'.$params['email'];

$html  .= 'Your Business Name'.$params['business_name'];

$html  .= 'Your Business Address'.$params['business_address'];

$html  .= 'Your Telephone Number'.$params['telephone_number'];

$mail->setBodyText($html);

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski, The answer is missing `.` before `<br />` tag. Please add it and check.

Comment: try it now @Grzegorz Wisniewski